# Tab focus granting event

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, dom-events

I need to capture tab focus granting event in Firefox browser. Is there any type of listener implement for this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Detecting tab selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_tab_selection) section of the [Tabbed browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) article explains how to detect when a tab is selected.